# React Native Remove Input Border (for Android 4.4.2)

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, react-native-textinput

This is shown on phones with a `low Android version`(4.4.2). Even though I removed the input border, it still looks like a border. Is there a prop to remove it

Image:

[image]

My `TextInput` code

```
<TextInput
            returnKeyType={'search'}
            multiline={false}
            underlineColorAndroid={'transparent'}
            autoCorrect={false}
            onChangeText={(text) => props.searchValueChange(text)}
            keyboardShouldPersistTaps="always"
            onFocus={() => {
              props.setFocus(true);
              transitionRef.current.animateNextTransition();
            }}
            value={props?.header?.searchValue}
            placeholderTextColor={'rgba(240,240,240,.5)'}
            placeholder="Type to search"
            style={Style.textInput}
            onSubmitEditing={() => handleLeaver(false)}
            ref={_textInput}
          />
```

My `Style` const:

```
const Style = StyleSheet.create({
    textInput: {
      paddingRight: 10,
      width: '100%',
      height: '100%',
      color: WHITE, // WHITE = '#fefeff'
    },
    },
  });
```

Comment: You're accessing `textInput` style out of `Style` object not `styles` ... is that intended ? if yes,plz share your style-obj

Comment: Yes normal, I updated my question. You can look at the `Style` const.

Comment: react-native version ?

Comment: "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "0.63.2",
    "cli" : "2.0.1"

Comment: have you tried `autoCorrect={false}`?

Comment: @MohamadKh75 , still the same

Comment: @EminTAYFUR I already have a physical-device running android 4.4.2 ... and there's no underline in the TextInput without even applying `underlineColorAndroid`